# Set IBAction for edit button in NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, navigationbar

How to set an IBAction for the edit button in the NavigationBar created using the following code
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to set an IBAction rather than just an action via a selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are assigning the left bar button programmatically, you must create the button yourself. When you instantiating the button, you can also set the callback action something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
     target:self
     action:@selector(editButtonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

When the edit button is pressed, the following method will be called

```
- (void)editButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already working in code, rather than Interface Builder, it's probably easier to assign a selector programmatically as well:

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(doSomething:)];
```